# NOT Combination with AND

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause, sql-null

I am trying to query a list of rows from the database.
It has 7 fields (columns) (A,B,C,VA,VB,VC,LISTED).

```
SELECT * FROM datas WHERE 
        ((A=1 OR A IS NULL) AND (B=1 OR B IS NULL) AND (C=1 OR C IS NULL))  -- A/B/C are either 1 or NULL
        AND (VA=1 AND VB=1 AND VC=1)    -- VA/VB/VC must ALL be 1
        AND LISTED=0
        AND NOT (A=1 AND B=1 AND C=1)   -- BUT A/B/C must NOT be ALL 1 (at least one NULL)
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Everything is working until i add the `AND NOT` line. It returns no row.

To explain it shorter, i want to retrieve all rows where A/B/C are either 1 or NULL but not ALL to 1.

And VA/VB/VC must be all to 1. (and LISTED is well 0)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Everything is working until i add the AND NOT line. It returns no row.

The problem is comparisons against `null` values in the `NOT` predicate. `A = 1` returns `null` when A is null, then `NOT (NULL)` is still `NULL`. Obviously this is not the behavior you want.

Instead, you can use `<=>`, which performs null-safe equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE 
    COALESCE(A, 1) = 1 AND COALESCE(B, 1) = 1 AND COALESCE(C, 1) = 1 -- A/B/C are either 1 or NULL
    AND VA = 1 AND VB = 1 AND VC = 1 -- VA/VB/VC must ALL be 1
    AND LISTED=0
    AND NOT (A <=> 1 AND B <=> 1 AND C <=> 1)   -- BUT A/B/C must NOT be ALL 1 (at least one NULL)
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Notes:

- `COALESCE()` can be used to shorten the first predicate
- Parentheses around `AND` conditions are superfluous (second predicate)

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks for the explainations about the NULL behavior.

Answer (score 2):

in mysql comparisons return 0 or 1 so they can be summed

```
SELECT * FROM datas WHERE 
        ((A=1 OR A IS NULL) AND (B=1 OR B IS NULL) AND (C=1 OR C IS NULL))  -- A/B/C are either 1 or NULL
        AND (VA=1 AND VB=1 AND VC=1)    -- VA/VB/VC must ALL be 1
        AND LISTED=0
        AND ((A IS NULL) +( B IS NULL) + ( C IS NULL)) Between 1 and 2
```

-- BUT A/B/C must NOT be ALL 1 (at least one NULL)
ORDER BY ID ASC

Comment: If i understand, i should use `<3` in place of the `>0` in your code ?

Comment: yes you are right if

Comment: no it hasn't it check is at least one is null